# NP COMPLETE and NP HARD

Tags: algorithm

I have to check out whether my logic is on the right path.

**NP-HARD**: these are the hardest problems which may/may not be in NP class. If you have an efficient algorithm for these problems you have one for every problem in class NP.

**NP COMPLETE**: these are the hardest problems in class NP and also if you solve one of these you could solve any problem in class NP. So, NP COMPLETE problem is an NP-HARD problem.

**COOK'S THEOREM**: If SAT(NP-HARD) has a polynomial time algorithm then so does every problem in class NP.

Now, suppose we have to prove that CDP(clique decision problem) is **NP COMPLETE**.

->Step 1: Prove that CDP is in the class **NP**.
  It is in class NP because the prover can generate a proof for yes inputs which would enable the verifier to check that it is a CDP (has a clique of size k).

->Step 2: Prove that CDP is **NP HARD**.
 For that, we can convert the SAT to CDP by constructing a graph from clauses and supplying k.
 We supply(G,k) to the clique subroutine which would verify is there a clique of size k or not. If it can figure this out in polynomial time then SAT has a polynomial time algorithm as CDP had a polynomial time algorithm and we converted SAT to CDP. So, now we proved that if there is a polynomial time algorithm for CDP then there is for the SAT. Now if we can find a polynomial time algorithm for CDP then it would imply that there is a polynomial time algorithm for SAT. This would imply that there is a polynomial time algorithm for every problem in  **NP** by **COOK'S THEOREM.**

So we proved that CDP is **NP COMPLETE**. Once we have added CDP to **NP COMPLETE** class and now we come up with a new problem which we have again to prove that it is NP COMPLETE we can prove that problem to be in **NP** and then we could prove that if there is an efficient algorithm for given problem then that implies that there is an efficient algorithm for SAT/CDP(as we have added this to **NP COMPLETE**). Then as said above we can convert this problem to CDP/SAT and then prove that if there is an efficient algorithm for our problem then there is one for CDP/SAT and then by COOK'S THEOREM again we have that if there is a solution to NP-HARD problem (in this case CDP/SAT) then there is one for every problem in NP. So we again proved our problem as NP-HARD and as now it also belongs to **NP** as said above it is **NP COMPLETE**.

So we can add as many problems to the NP COMPLETE class as long as we can convert some problem which is already in NP-HARD class(in this case SAT/CDP) into our problem and we should find an efficient algorithm to our problem  which would indirectly find an efficient algorithm to the **NP-HARD** problem and by COOK's theorem we can say that as some **NP-HARD** problem has an efficient algorithm we have an efficient algorithm to solve all problems in **NP**.

Comment: What specifically is your question? I think this is correct, but I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: i need to know whether its correct or not

Comment: Answering this question requires a lot of in-depth analysis and theoretical knowledge, probably more than is typically appropriate for [so]. Perhaps this question would be better suited on [cs.se] or [cstheory.se] (can't say for sure though).

Comment: Yeah, I would reccomend the Theoretical Computer Science...I know my advanced algorithms professor from U of I lurks there.

Comment: I stand corrected, I see the theorists did not take kindly to your question!

Comment: You're misusing the word "efficient" to mean "polynomial-time."  We already have a word for that; it's "polynomial-time."  Other than that, your reasoning is basically sound.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path, but there your logic is a little incomplete.

The general structure of your proof is correct: First prove a problem is in NP, then prove the problem is NP-Hard. Those two bits of information together prove that a problem is NP-Complete.

Your proof for proving a problem is in NP is incomplete. Here are the key components to proving a problem is in NP:

1. Reword the problem as a decision problem that can be answered with a yes or a no.
2. Describe what a "certificate" would be. NOTE: a certificate is an output that can be checked to verify the answer to the decision problem. For CDP it could be a list of vertices and edges that make up the clique of size k.
3. Prove that this certificate can be verified in polynomial time.

Your proof for proving NP-Hard is incomplete. Here are the key components to proving a problem is NP-Hard:

1. Transform the input of the known NP-Hard problem into the input for the problem you are trying to prove.
2. Prove that this transformation can be done in polynomial time.
3. Transform the output of the problem your trying to prove into the output of the known NP-Hard problem.
4. Demonstrate how this can be done in polynomial time.
5. Prove that if you get an answer for the problem you are trying to prove, then you have an answer for the known problem.
6. Prove that if you get an answer for the known problem you have an answer for the problem you are trying to prove.

Only by meeting those 6 criterion can you say you have completely proven that a problem is NP-Hard.

Besides the specifics on that your logic is sound. Be careful when saying "efficient" if you really mean "can be solved in polynomial time".